# Scrollbars in jqgrid without data populated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am trying to use jqgrid to create a grid which has no data initially but has a fixed size, where the columns width in total is greater than the grids width, so that user can only scroll through the headers. User will click a button which will populate the data into the grid. This might sound similar to the already answered question [jqGrid vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502628/jqgrid-vertical-scrollbar)

However, in that case, the data was already there. I do not have the data initially and want the grid to have the scrollbars. I noticed that the div with class .ui-jqgrid-bdiv doesnt get created until you populate the data.

Is this a bug in jqgrid? Is there any workaround for this?

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/2630/

Here is the code:

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#results").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 150,
        scroll:true,
        width:300,
        shrinkToFit:false,
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 160, sorttype: "int" },
            { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
            { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
            { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 180, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 280, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
           ],
       });
            var mydata = [
                            { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                            { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                            { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
                            { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                            { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                            { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
                            { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                            { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                            { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
                            ];
            //if you uncomment this, the scrollbars would appear
            /*for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
                $("#results").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);*/
        });
```

html

```
<div>
    <table id="results"></table>
</div>
```

EDIT:
To be more clear, in the above example, I want to horizontally scroll through the headers. When the data is populated, the header should remain static when scrolling vertically, and scroll horizontally along with data.

Thanks!

Comment: column declaration is different when compared with `mydata`.

Answer (score 1):

@user1719160:

```
loadComplete: function () {

        if ($(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount') == 0)
        {         
            $(".jqgfirstrow").css("height","1px");
        }
```

this works... is not very elegant... but it does the work.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the header visible during vertical scroll see Oleg's answer at:
[fixing column headers while scrolling - jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686944/fixing-column-headers-while-scrolling-jqgrid)

To enable the header scroll you can do this in the load complete

```
 loadComplete: function () {
        if ($(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount') == 0){
          $(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv").css("overflow-x", "auto")
        }
          else{
              $(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv").css("overflow-x", "hidden")
          }

    }//loadComplete
```

Comment: Well that will have scrolls for the whole div, but then, the problem is that the header would also scroll along with data when the data is populated. The header wont act like a header which I dont want.

Comment: So you want the header of the jqGrid to remain static and the data columns to scroll?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Also, when data isnt there, the headers should be visible.

Comment: May I ask how keeping the headers static while scrolling the data below will make sense to the user? In your example the headers are visible before the data is loaded.

Comment: By static, I mean the header should remain as a separate section and always visible since when the user scrolls the data, he knows what column belongs to what header. So if you check this updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/2644/ the header is static and you can scroll the data. By giving scroll to the entire div, the header would move with data which I dont want. I hope I am clear.

Comment: @user1719160 Nope, you have lost me or we are not using the same terms.  In the example the column headers scroll with the data rows when you horizontal scroll.  This would be the desired behavior in my mind, and I"m not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about vertical scroll. The header would scroll with the data columns when you have overflow:scroll to outer div.

Comment: Hi, The header remains visible when there is data in it. My question is when there is no data and only headers, at that time the headers arent visible completely, only those which are visible in the grids viewport as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/2630/). I want to horizontally scroll through the headers.

Comment: @user1719160 So the example you link. Are the column headers visible: YES If you want horizontal scroll turn on `overflow-x: scroll;`

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/2630/) is what happens when you turn on `overflow-x:scroll;` on the outerdiv

Comment: @user1719160 You didn't link anything.

Comment: @user1719160 The edit I just provided is working in your fiddle and displaying the header scrollbar, I don't have time to get it working for the bottom scroll bar but that should put you on the right path.

Comment: Hey, this gives me scrollbar at the header level, I want to below. Anyhow, the best bet for me would to insert a blank row, and then it displays the scrollbar of the data's div(ui-jqgrid-bdiv). And when I insert some 'real' data, I will remove that blank row or do `display:none;`. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your time and efforts.

Comment: @user1719160 Please upvote/mark as correct if this put you on the right path.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to upvote it :( However, this is not the answer, as putting the scroll on the header div is not right. This will show horizontal scroll just below the header and it doesnt look good. The scroll should be at the bottom of the assigned height of the grid, not at the header. The best hack I found is to insert a blank row, just `<tr><td></td></tr>` after the 1st row containing the meta data for the rows. Once you insert the data, remove this row. Anyhow, I will wait for the right answer. I will upvote once I have enough reputation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is the final solution that I found for hbar in the jqgrid when there is no data.

```
loadComplete: function () {
    if ($(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount') == 0)
    {                
        $("#grid > tbody").append("<tr id=\"my_row\" role=\"row\"><td colspan=\"15\" style=\"height:1px;\" role=\"gridcell\"></td></tr>")
    }        
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else comes across it, the following code worked well for me (change **grid_client** to the proper name):

```
loadBeforeSend: function() {
    var headerWidth = $('#gview_grid_client .ui-jqgrid-hdiv div:first').width();
    $('#gview_grid_client .ui-jqgrid-bdiv div:first').css({
        width: headerWidth,
        height: 1
    })
}
```

Found the solution [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/horizontal-scroll-missing-on-empty-table/).  This work well in my situation, because I have filters on my columns & need to maintain the horizontal scroll position if someone selects a filter, there are no results, and then unselects that filter to repopulate the table.  Without the added code, the table repopulates and resets data & scrollbar to the left, but the headers remain scrolled to the right.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Almost a decade later and this issue still needs a manual fix for some reason.

In case anyone comes across this, a generalized solution would be as follows:

```js
_createNoDataRow: function() {

    return $('<tr>')
        .addClass(this.noDataRowClass)
        .append($('<td>')
        .addClass(this.cellClass)
        .attr('colspan', this.fields.length)
        .attr('width', this._headerRow.width())
        .append(this.renderTemplate(this.noDataContent, this)));
},
```

This `_createNoDataRow` callback (not documented) gets called upon the creation of a "no data" row and allows you to create it yourself. We're essentially just adding the `width` attribute to the "no data" to be equal to the header's width, triggering the x overflow over the grid's body and showing a scroll.

***Note***: worth pointing out that if the header's width is too large, the "not found" text might get shifted off the screen. In this case, you might need to transpose it back using CSS or so as to not compromise the UX.